# UserForm in middle postion of second UserForm

Tags: vba, userform

All,

I have UserForm in Outlook with command button to display another UserForm.
I would like to display the second UserForm in the middle position of first UserForm.
Is there easy way to do that?

Edit:
When user click show second userform it is display in right side of monitor. I would like to display exacly in the midle of the previous. Additionaly sometimes this new form lost focus and I need to click on outlook to see him.

Thank you,
TJ

Comment: What is the importance of the placement?

Comment: Not sure what you are asking for. When user click show second userform it is display in right side of monitor. I would like to display exacly in midle of the previous. Additionaly sometimes this new form lost focus and I need to click on outlook to see him.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where the UserForm starts can be set with the `StartUpPosition` property of the UserForm itself.

See here for the documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251352(v=office.15).aspx

You can set this property to `1` (which is the default) or `CenterOwner` which means the UserForm will start center to the item to which the UserForm belongs.

Comment: When I use: "StartUpPosition = 2" it works and it is displayed in center of screen. But when I use "StartUpPosition = 1" it is not displayed in the center of previous UserForm. I will probably switch both form to display in center of screen. Thank you.

Comment: Are you using dual screens out of interest as this has been a problem fore before?

Comment: We are using 3 monitors.

Comment: I don't know why but I find multiple monitors can cause inconsistent behaviour with where the user form loads

Comment: Gareth, one more question. New UserForm pop up in the fron of the previous one. I need to click on outlook application to show it. Is there any way to force showing this userform in the front of previous? Thanks.

Comment: UserForm loads a while and it happens when user in this time will use other app, for example browser, than he need to click outlook to see new userform. So I need to find the way to set focus on new form from other app.